# Android unique click events on dynamic added buttons

Tags: java, android

For my app I add buttons to my listview dynamicly based on an arrayList. I add the buttons like this:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.groupsButtonList);

for(int index = 0; index < groupsList.size(); index++){

    Group singleGroup = groupsList.get(index);
    Button myButton = new Button(this);
    myButton.setText(singleGroup.name);
    AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams( AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ll.addView(myButton, lp);
}
```

I loop through all Group items from an arraylist. and add the buttons to the listview. Thiw works great.

What i want to do now is be able to know on which button/item the user clicked. The model of the Group object also contains an _id it would be the best if I could add it to the button and get it from an on button click event. If I could only get the position of the button in the list (for example the 4th button in the list should return 4 or 3 if the 1st returns 0 ) than i could get it from the arrayList based on index. All help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to use the View's tag, and set an OnClickListener to each button that expects the clicked view to have a tag of that type set on it before it's clicked.  For example:

```
OnClickListener groupClickListener = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        Group clickedGroup = (Group) v.getTag();
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
};

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.groupsButtonList);

for(int index = 0; index < groupsList.size(); index++){
        Group singleGroup = groupsList.get(index);
        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setTag(singleGroup);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(groupClickListener);
        myButton.setText(singleGroup.name);
}
```